# Change the shape of floating action button

Tags: android

I want to add a floating action button into my layout. would like to ask how to customized and change the shape of floating action button to your own icon?

Comment: do you tried any thing or do you search in google for the same?

Comment: @Sree, i have googled. I think the best way is create button with customized icon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the "shape" then you'll probably have to create your own implementation of FAB with a custom shape, perhaps rectangular or square.

To change the icon, you just have to use the `android:src` attribute and point to the appropriate drawable. FAB is nothing more than an `ImageView` with super powers.

Comment: thanks, You are right. i guess i will create a button if i want to customized my own icon or shape.

Comment: No, you dont have to create your own button by subclassing FAB if all u want to do is change the icon it displays. For that, there's the `android:src` attribute.

Comment: I have tried, the shape will appear in the circle of floating button,hence better to create own button

Comment: @LittleChild maybe there is some example of its implementation? I want to make the button oval.