# Is it possible to change the fab back with a custom drawable resource?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to change the fab background with my own drawable color is it possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rot"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:text="B">

    </Button>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@color/delete"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"

        ></com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This drawable is set as background but not working for fab background?**
[image]

Comment: Please this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938907/7954210

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeOverlay.Fab"
      ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeOverlay.Fab" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">48%</item>
</style>
```

[image]